# Error: could not find skywalking: stat skywalking: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skywalking

I am follow this [docs](https://github.com/apache/skywalking-kubernetes/) to install skywalking using helm 3.2.1 :

```
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
helm dep up skywalking
```

but when I execute the second command:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm dep up skywalking
Error: could not find skywalking: stat skywalking: no such file or directory
```

and I create skywalking directory:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ mkdir skywalking
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm dep up skywalking
Error: validation: chart.metadata is required
```

so what should I do to make it work? This is I am trying follow:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 chart]$ helm dep up skywalking
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "incubator" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "riskfocus" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "traefik" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "elastic" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading elasticsearch from repo https://helm.elastic.co/
Deleting outdated charts
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 chart]$ helm install apm-skywalking skywalking -n monitoring
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: PodDisruptionBudget "elasticsearch-master-pdb" in namespace "monitoring" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "apm-skywalking": current value is "elasticsearch"
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 chart]$ helm install skywalking --generate-name -n monitoring
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: PodDisruptionBudget "elasticsearch-master-pdb" in namespace "monitoring" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "skywalking-1591790123": current value is "elasticsearch"
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 chart]$ helm install elasticsearch skywalking -n monitoring
Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clone the repository to your machine,

```
$ git clone git@github.com:apache/skywalking-kubernetes.git
```

2. Go to `Chart` directory,

```
$ cd skywalking-kubernetes/chart
```

3. Now perform the following commands (from `chart` dir),

```sh
$ helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co

$ helm dep up skywalking

$ helm install <release_name> skywalking -n <namespace>
```